# Centos 6.10 Swap File Issue Wrong size

Tags: centos, swap

I have Centos 6.10 Server with initial swap of 3.81 GB working ok no issue.

I noticed wrong swap today amount of 4kb. I tried removing the partition and recreate entry on fstab and remount but no avail. Also tried creating swapfile 8GB using fallocate -l 8G /home/swapfile and added on fstab swapon -a. Still doesn't work.

Below are some info on system:

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

**`mkswap command`**

[image]

Comment: Have you run `mkswap /home/swapfile` after file creating?

Comment: yes I did i will add another screen cap to be sure

Answer (score 2):

You should create swap file system and enable swap with `swapon`. Swap could be created by command `mkswap`.

`mkswap /home/swapfile` for file and `mkswap /dev/sdX` for partition, see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275963/making-a-swap-partition-using-lvm) answer.

Comment: yes I did i will add another screen cap to be sure

Comment: still same issue